# Long-standing poll questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, polling

I've come across a couple of poll questions

- [What Delphi coding standards document(s) do you follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262892/what-delphi-coding-standards-documents-do-you-follow)
- [Distributed Computing Framework (.NET) - Specifically for CPU Intensive operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755180/distributed-computing-framework-net-specifically-for-cpu-intensive-operatio)

Both are quite old, have a score >12, numerous favourites and no downvotes. I found them as both have multiple answers by the OP.

I've seen a lot of anti-poll conclusions on meta which I tend to agree so have voted to close but there are a selection of older polls which are still around. Are they kept for historical reasons or is it just that nobody's noticed/had time to close?

In any case I've voted to close

Comment: Asked in a time where that was okay. Gone unnoticed since then. If they would have been purposefully kept for historical reasons, they might have had a historical lock on them.

Comment: ...and now the questions are properly closed. The MSO Eye of Sauron has found its targets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made a binding vote to close on both.

If you come across these organically, vote to close and move on. If it looks like there is recent activity that may cause a problem, flag it.

Otherwise, there's no really good reason to worry about old posts ( or bring them up on Meta), we have plenty of new posts that need attention. [There's even a chat room devoted to this sort of thing](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/posse-comitatus). I recommend using it.

Comment: +1 agreed - if you see it, close it. The main problem with this type of question going unnoticed is that people use it as an example - and even as a defense - for posting new shopping list questions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your "Don't worry about old posts" line? Are old posts less likely to turn up in search results? If not, then why shouldn't they be tidied up if possible?

Comment: @Basic I think he just means that if you post a new meta question for every old list question, you'll quickly take over meta. If you see an old list question, VtC, if you're not sure, skip it (or potentially bring it up in the chat room he's off finding).

Comment: @Basic We have a finite amount of time in the day. You do as well. It's more helpful to us to use that time to deal with the glaring problems that are showing up in visits today than to hunt down old posts and close them because they're no longer on topic.  That's why I said, "if you come across them *organically*", instead of searching them out.  It's disappointing to come across flags where people obviously conducted an SEDE search for specific text and then started flagging all the old questions just because they had that text. I tend to decline some of those flags (for this very reason).